# how to display database(name, photo, status and address) from firebase in listview?

Tags: database, firebase, listview

this app doesn't use profile image as profile photo. but i want to add it with firebase.
I want to add/change from icon to user photo profile, data from firebase
I've tried it with the code below, everything in the user list turns into my photo, so it's weird.
please help me what should i do.how to display database(name, photo, status and address) from firebase in listview?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfdyk.jpg)
the result is like in this picture, the user photos are all the same

```
MyActivity Code:
```

```
@Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            getLocation();
            View view2 = view;
            Object item = getItem(i);
            boolean z = item instanceof Channel;
            String str = "";
            if (z) {
                Channel channel = (Channel) item;
                if (view2 == null || view2.findViewById(R.id.channelname1) == null) {
                    view2 = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_channel2, viewGroup, false);
                }
                TextView textView = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.channelname1);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.chantopic);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.channelicon);
                Button join = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.join_btn2);
                int icon_resource = R.drawable.inbox;
                if(channel.bPassword) {
                    icon_resource = R.drawable.ic_lock;
                    imageView.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.text_passwdprot));
                    imageView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
                }
                else {
                    imageView.setContentDescription(null);
                    imageView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
                }
                imageView.setImageResource(icon_resource);
                textView.setText(channel.szName);
                textView2.setText(channel.szTopic);
                int size = Utils.getUsers(channel.nChannelID, MainActivity.this.ttservice.getUsers()).size();
                if (size > 0) {
                    str = String.format("%d ", Integer.valueOf(size));
                }
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.population);
                textView3.setText(str);
                if (size > 0) {
                    str = String.format("%d ", Integer.valueOf(size));
                }
                if(channel.nParentID == 0) {
                    // show server name as channel name for root channel
                    ServerProperties srvprop = new ServerProperties();
                    ttclient.getServerProperties(srvprop);
                    textView.setText(srvprop.szServerName);
                    viewptt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch(v.getId()) {
                            case R.id.join_btn2 : {
                                joinChannel(channel);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                };
                join.setOnClickListener(listener);
                join.setAccessibilityDelegate(accessibilityAssistant);
                join.setEnabled(channel.nChannelID != ttclient.getMyChannelID());

            }
            else if (item instanceof dk.bearware.User) {
                dk.bearware.User user = (dk.bearware.User) item;
                if (view2 == null || view2.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername) == null) {
                    view2 = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_users_grid, viewGroup, false);
                }
                imgBGWhite = view2.findViewById(R.id.imgBGWhite);
                imgOff = view2.findViewById(R.id.imgOff);
                imgOn = view2.findViewById(R.id.imgOn);
               mImageView = (CircleImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView txtLastDate= (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.txtLastDate);
                TextView txtLastMsg= (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.txtLastMsg);
                TextView txtUnreadCounter= (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.txtUnreadCounter);
                mTxtUsername = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
                status = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.status);
                txtLocationCity = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.alamatKota);
                txtLastDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtUnreadCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                status.setText(status1);
                txtLocationCity.setText(location);
                firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                assert firebaseUser != null;
                currentId = firebaseUser.getUid();

                reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(REF_USERS).child(currentId);
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        try {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                                final User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                assert user != null;
                                status.setText(user.getAbout());
                                txtLocationCity.setText(user.getUserAlamatKota());
                               Utils.setProfileImage(getApplicationContext(), user.getImageURL(), mImageView1);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                mTxtUsername.setText(Utils.getDisplayName(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), user));
               
                try {
                    int size2 = Utils.getUsers(MainActivity.this.curchannel.nChannelID, MainActivity.this.ttservice.getUsers()).size();
                    TextView textView11 = MainActivity.this.recUserOnline;
                    textView11.setText(size2 + str);
                    textView11.setTextColor(YELLOW);
                    MainActivity.this.channelSekarang = MainActivity.this.curchannel.nChannelID;
                    MainActivity.this.textInfoChannel.setText(MainActivity.this.curchannel.szTopic);
                    TextView textView10 = textChannelSekarang;
                    textView10.setText(curchannel.szName + str);
                } catch (Exception unused3) {
                }
                boolean talking = (user.uUserState & UserState.USERSTATE_VOICE) != 0;
                boolean female = (user.nStatusMode & TeamTalkConstants.STATUSMODE_FEMALE) != 0;
                boolean away =  (user.nStatusMode & TeamTalkConstants.STATUSMODE_AWAY) != 0;
                if(user.nUserID == ttservice.getTTInstance().getMyUserID()) {
                    talking = ttservice.isVoiceTransmitting();
                }

                if(talking) {
                    String name1 = Utils.getDisplayName(getBaseContext(), user);
                    mTxtUsername.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.user_state_now_speaking, name1));
                    if(female) {
                        imgBGWhite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imgOn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imgOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else {
                        imgBGWhite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imgOn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imgOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    imgBGWhite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgOn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
            view2.setAccessibilityDelegate(MainActivity.this.accessibilityAssistant);
            return view2;
        }
```

```
User code:
```

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String imageURL;
    private String status;
    private String search;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean typing;
    private String typingwith;
    private String about;
    private String gender;
    private String lastSeen;
    private String userAlamat;
    private boolean isChecked;
    private boolean isAdmin;
    private boolean isHost;
    private boolean isCoHost;
    private int userJenis = 0;
    private String userNEGARA;
    private String userPROVINSI;
    private String userKOTA;



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public boolean isTyping() {
        return typing;
    }

    public void setTyping(boolean typing) {
        this.typing = typing;
    }

    public String getTypingwith() {
        return typingwith;
    }

    public void setTypingwith(String typingwith) {
        this.typingwith = typingwith;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getLastSeen() {
        return lastSeen;
    }

    public void setLastSeen(String lastSeen) {
        this.lastSeen = lastSeen;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        isAdmin = admin;
    }

    public boolean isHost() {
        return isHost;
    }

    public void setHost(boolean host) {
        isHost = host;
    }

    public boolean isCoHost() {
        return isCoHost;
    }

    public void setCoHost(boolean cohost) {
        isCoHost = cohost;
    }




    public String setUserJenis(int i) {
        this.userJenis = i;
        return null;
    }

    public int getUserJenis() {
        return this.userJenis;
    }

    public String getUserAlamatKota() {
        return userKOTA;
    }

    public void setUserAlamatKota(String userKOTA) {
        this.userKOTA = userKOTA;
    }


    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", userKOTA='" + userKOTA + '\'' +
                ", userPROVINSI='" + userPROVINSI + '\'' +
                ", userNEGARA='" + userNEGARA + '\'' +
                ", imageURL='" + imageURL + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", search='" + search + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", active=" + active +
                ", typing=" + typing +
                ", typingwith='" + typingwith + '\'' +
                ", about='" + about + '\'' +
                ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                ", lastSeen='" + lastSeen + '\'' +
                ", isChecked=" + isChecked +
                '}';
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @Alex Mamo
the error is  photoprofile, status is the same for all users, like this image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfdyk.jpg

Comment: I cannot see any error in the image.

Comment: Both user photoprofiles are the same, each user should be different...